# Link to other nodes

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

I am starting a Drupal 8 website, with five custom Node types. These Node types need a field that can link to an arbitrary number of Nodes of any type. All information that I've found online is pertinent to Drupal 7 only. For instance, the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module (included already in Drupal 8, but in D8 does not support Node references), or the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module (not available for D8).

**How can I create a field to link to an abitrary number of Nodes in Drupal 8?**

Comment: Entity reference field type does support nodes and users in Drupal 8. Is there an error message that you are running into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 8 this is built in. You probably don't find it, because drupal 8 uses the name "content type" not "node type".

You go to manage fields in the content type, add a new field, in select a field type choose Reference - Content. In the field settings you can choose which content type you want to link to.

Comment: Thank you. I have two issues with this field type. First, it only seems to support a single link, not an arbitrary number of links. Can it support multiple links? Two, it does not display a list of all items, one must guess a leading letter of the item to link to before getting a list of links to attach. Can this be worked around? Thank you!

Comment: You can configure multiple links in "Allowed number of values" in the field settings. The autocomplete widget is default, you can change this in "Manage form display".